# Is below language recursive?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

$$L = \{  \langle M \rangle  \mid  M \text{ takes at least 2016 steps on all input } \}$$

My approach

As $M$ takes atleast 2016 steps, only tape cells 0,1,..2015 are significant. Now we have finite number of strings of length 2016.

As we have finite number of strings with finite length, we can simulate $M$ on each of these strings in finite amount of time.

For all strings with length greater than 2016, the behaviour of TM for these strings would be same as for the prefix of those strings (first 2016 input symbols).

So above language is recursive.

My book says answer as recursive but it doesn't have any explanation so I don't know if my explanation regarding whether the language is recursive is right or wrong.

I have just one doubt with the above intuition. In the question we have **atleast** 2016 steps. Now according to the intuition, if we have a string of length 2019 and if a prefix of length 2016 doesn't halt within 2016 steps then it doesn't belong to language. But what if the string of length 2019 halts on 2018th step, then it belongs to language but we are not considering that. Should we also consider that ? I know that my intuition is correct if question would have been **atmost** 2016 steps.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Your intuition is correct. Maybe try to formalize the proof to convince yourself?

Comment: @quicksort Please check my edit. I have one doubt.

Comment: You have asked many questions. Why are you still trying to go by your intuition? Try *proving* things. (Accurate) Intuition will come from rigor, not the other way around.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Start by proving that $L=\{\langle M\rangle | M \mbox{ takes at least 2016 steps on all inputs of length $\leq 2017$}\}$. Note that the language property does not consider what happens after $2016$ steps: $M$ might diverge or halt, but that's completely irrelevant. the property only requires that $M$ does not halt before $2016$ steps, on all inputs.

Comment: @chi if the question would have been **halts** on at least 2016 steps on all inputs, then it would be non R.E right ? As an input might take any number of steps more than 2016 to halt and we can't be sure if it will halt in near future.

Comment: @Zephyr If that means "M takes at least 2016 steps, and then halts, on all inputs" then yes, it would not be r.e. since it is a minor variation of $TOT$ (which is not r.e.). Indeed you can reduce $TOT$ to that, I think. Just force $M$ to do 2016 "no-op" steps and continue as before.